# Unable to view display on external monitor [Asus Zenbook UX330 | Ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, external-monitor

I have an Asus Zenbook UX330 running only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I cannot connect to my television through the micro HDMI port.  All of the cables appear to be working correctly, and the television's HDMI port is also working correctly.  I've read through every related question, and none of the suggestions have gotten me any closer.  Specifically...

- I have all of the latest updates installed
- I've removed xserver-xorg-video-intel (sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel)
- I've updated the Intel video drivers (intel-graphics-update-tool)
- I installed the Hardware Enablement stack (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)
- I disabled UEFI secure boot
- I've tried manually adding a mode to HDMI-1 using xrandr, but it fails ("xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed")

Here are my various outputs:

```
lshw -C video  

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:126 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`xrandr` (with the mode manually added to HDMI-1)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96
```

I'm seriously at a loss.  If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.  I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: What happens when you connect the micro HDMI cable and then run this command? `xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as eDP-1` and then also run `xrandr` and paste the output of the commands please.

Comment: When I run that exact command, I get the following error: "xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080"

When I run a slightly different version of the command (`xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00 --same-as eDP-1`), I get the same error mentioned above: "xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed"

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've been away. It appears to be EDID related which "may" be caused by the HDMI cable in use. Have you got another HDMI cable (different brand) to try? If yes, that would be great. Another thing, could you please run the following command and tell us what the output says? `sudo lshw -C video | grep driver=` I want to see what driver is currently in use. EDID tells the source (in your case the PC) what the extended display is capable of + make/model and in your case it knows nothing about it hence for questioning the cable in use (or the graphics driver)

Comment: I don't have another micro HDMI to HDMI cable (I've tried plugging it directly into the television and also with an extension cable), but I'm getting a USB-C to HDMI cable (it arrives tomorrow) to see if that will work instead.  I included the lshw -C video output above in my original question -- the driver is i915 (and it didn't work before and after I updated the driver with intel-graphics-update-tool).

Comment: I believe you will have more issues with USB-C to HDMI

Comment: Well, it can't be any worse than my issue with micro HDMI to HDMI.

Comment: Btw, I found something that should help you. See this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/736625/xrandr-does-not-connect-to-intel-i915-hdmi-output - "xrandr does not “connect” to intel i915 HDMI output" and this: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92685 " [i915 Skylake] HDMI output does not work with some adapters" so it looks like you are not the only one experiencing this issue. At least you know it's not the cable.